# Is there a word to describe a person who always buys what's new?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I mean, is there a word that describes a person who follows the latest stuff? For example, someone who waits desperately for iPhone 6 to come out so he can be the first person who has it among his friends. So he can show off and feel like he is the coolest person in the world.

Comment: Yes,  [**shallow**](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/shallow)

Comment: Call me shallow if you will, but I am **up to the minute** and you are not.

Answer (score 3):

A person who is quick to follow latest trends is, well, **[trendy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/trendy)**

> A person who is very fashionable or **up to date:**
>
> *Taiwan’s well-heeled young trendies*

Although this doesn't quite capture that he does it to "show off and feel like he is the coolest person in the world."

For that, try

**[swanky](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/swanky)**

> fashionable and expensive in a way that is intended to impress people
>
> *a swanky new hotel*

PS - note that `swanky` is approving. You sound like you need a word that's disapproving.

Comment: Good suggestions. My only issue with "trendy" is that trends are often retro in nature. For example search for "dumb phone trend" and you'll find many hits about people who are eschewing the latest phones to be hip. However Trendoid (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/trendoid) may work well; "A person who follows fashion blindly or excessively". It has the appropriate negative connotation as well.

Answer (score 2):

This would be an ***"early adopter"***.

> In the diffusion of innovation theory, the minority group (comprising about 14 percent) of population which, after innovators, is first to try new ideas, processes, goods and services. Early adopters generally rely on their on intuition and vision, choose carefully, and have above-average education level. For any new product to be successful, it must attract innovators and early adopters, so that its acceptance or 'diffusion' moves on to early majority, late majority, and then on to laggards.

Read more: http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/early-adopters.html

Comment: That's an awfully good suggestion. I think I may have heard it elsewhere, about 3 hours before your post. 8^>

Comment: @Alan K I read right across that one...it was at the tail not the start of your post.

Answer (score 1):

I could probably suggest "fool" and be accurate enough, but I suspect it may put some noses out of joint if the wrong people find this answer in their search results. (Really people, It. Is. A. Phone. Nobody who has a sense of priorities cares.)

I'm not aware of a single word that's commonly in use. However the most common ***expression*** that I've come across is [Early Adopter](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/early-adopter?q=Early%20adopter).

Answer (score 1):

Referring specifically to technology products as per you example, a slang expression is 
***[Technofreak](http://it.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Technofreak)***:

> - Somewhat like ***[technogeek](http://it.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Technogeek)***, a ***person who is obsessed with the latest technology,***  and everything techno-y, (music, clothing, etc), while still being able to straddle the line between nerd/geek and normal person, with a reasonalbe social life. They are also extremely adept at new technologies and are usually able to complete really complex technological things without becoming too unbalanced. Usually has a nostalgia for the 90's rave scene, even if they weren't involved in it.

(Urban Dictionary)

Comment: Along with technogeek and technofreak is technophile.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a good word for a person who likes or buys new things all the time is a:

Neophilia
/ (ˌniːəʊˈfɪlɪə) /
noun
a tendency to like anything new; love of novelty

Comment: Hello, Nico. It's important to add links to and to attribute quoted material. I believe you want the related concrete noun _neophile_.

Answer (score 0):

Modish is a possible word.

> **modish** ˈməʊdɪʃ/Submit adjective: modish conforming to or following what is currently popular and fashionable.[(Ref)](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20modish)